# Tumour cell injection into a mice

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cancer, cell-culture

I am going to inject mice tumour cells into mice to create them tumours and I am wondering if I need to have special precautions for that, even they are cells from mice tumour I am afraid what can happen if I inject myself by accident, I guess is not necessary to do it a hood either?

Comment: I hope you understand from the answers and comments that injecting mice (or any other thing) with live tumor cells is not without serious risks.

Answer (score 6):

You should not be asking random people on the internet about this. Talk to your lab safety people. Get detailed instructions on handling requirements. As for the hood, again, do not ask here, ask your animal care people (IACUC or equivalent).  If you don't have both lab safety people and animal care people immediately available and involved before the experiment begins, you should not be doing this experiment.

Comment: And you will most likely need a permission by an ethics comission.

Comment: IACUC is an ethics commission. If humans are not being experimented on, there probably won't be a need for a second ethics review.

Comment: Ah, I didn't knew this abbreviation. But since I have seen people who wanted to start immediately, I thought I mention it briefly...

Comment: +1 This is occupational safety and health for labs 101: If you develop a procedure, it needs to be reviewed to ensure the proper personnel, training, controls and PPE are available. *Before* you perform the procedure!